# Filewrite not happening when ofstream pointer is in a std::map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, ofstream

WRT below code, it compiles fine & also executes without any exception. But no content gets written to the javascript file. It's 0 bytes.

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> m_jsTabFilesMap;
m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ fileKey, std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(jsFilename) });
auto jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap[tabName];
(*jsFile).open(tabName + ".js");
*jsFile << contentofJSFile;  // write to JS file
```

**Not sure what did i miss, how do i make it write to file.**

**[UPDATES TO QUESTION]**
Using normal pointer method is also causing same result.

```
std::map<std::string,std::ofstream*> m_jsTabFilesMap;
m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ filekey, new std::ofstream(jsFilename)});
```

Also tried removing the explicit Open() call & same result, nothing gets written to file.

Comment: What is the type of `tabName`?  Could be important when using concatenation.

Comment: To debug code like this, start by simplifying. Create a shared pointer to `std::ofstream` and figure out how to write through it. Then put it into your map and see if it still works. That's pretty much all anyone can tell you with such a minimal snippet of code; there's no way to independently reproduce your results.

Comment: What is the return value when opening the file?  I recommend create a string variable with the filename, then passing to `open()`.  This allows you to see the actual filename when using the debugger.

Comment: [Off Topic] Is there as reason you're using a `std::shared_ptr` here?  This looks like something that `std::unique_ptr` can handle which removes the atomic reference counting cost.

Comment: `std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(jsFilename)` looks like you opened the file here, or tried to. and you tried to open it again here `(*jsFile).open(tabName + ".js");`. If the first open succeeded, that ends in the stream being in a fail state.

Comment: @user4581301 That should go in the answer section ;)

Comment: @user4581301: I tried removing the explicit open() but doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Using shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr because, I'm copying it as you can see here: auto jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap[tabName].   Can i do this with uniquee_ptr ?

Comment: @codeLover You can't copy it but you can get a reference like `auto& jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap[tabName];`

Comment: codeLover, what I commented about above is the only outright error in the code you have posted. If removing one of the `open`s doesn't solve the problem, then you have two or more bugs, and the additional bugs are not here. That said, you can probably simplify this greatly. You have `auto`, so you at least have c++11 and `emplace` and move semantics. Give something like `std::map<std::string, std::ofstream> m_jsTabFilesMap;
 m_jsTabFilesMap.emplace(fileKey, std::ofstream(jsFilename));
 auto &jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap[fileKey];` a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to files may be buffered for performance (by C++ lib, underling C lib, OS, etc., etc.) because storage devices can not directly write a few bytes at a time, but entire sectors (often 4096 or 512 bytes). Your data may not actually be written or be "visible" until it any buffers are "flushed". This will always happen when the file is closed or if the buffer is full (quite possibly many KB). But if you are storing it in a map you may not be waiting for it to be closed before checking?

To flush a file explicitly the `std::ostream::flush` method. Just remember there is a performance penalty for doing so.

Also you should check for errors. C++ streams dont by default throw exceptions in most cases, even if say opening a file fails, so you want to check its error state (e.g. `good()` or `fail()`). Allthough if as implied your code works with a normal stack allocated stream, the version using a stored map should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the given code snippet, the filestream is opened twice. Once here: `std::ofstream>(jsFilename)` and the other time `(*jsFile).open(tabName + ".js");`. Reopening a file stream places the stream in an error state and it can no longer be written. The obvious solution is to remove `(*jsFile).open(tabName + ".js");`

The next oddity is

```
m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ fileKey, std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(jsFilename) });
auto jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap[tabName];
```

The stream was mapped to `fileKey` and accessed with `tabName`. if `fileKey` is not equal to `tabName`, a different stream will be returned. If `tabName` does not exist in the `map`, the `map` will not fail, throw an exception, or warn you in any way. It will create a brand new, default constructed `ofstream`, and this stream WILL have to be opened, and it will likely fail to open if the file is already held open by the `fstream` in the `map`. You can prevent the creation of a new `fstream` and get a `std::out_of_range` exception by using `std::map::at` instead of `operator[]`

With additional checking to make sure all actions attempted are carried out successfully, the code should look something like:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>> m_jsTabFilesMap;

std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream> temp = make_shared<std::ofstream>(jsFilename);
if (*temp) // test if opened.
{
    m_jsTabFilesMap.insert({ fileKey,  temp}); // only add if opened!
}
else
{
    // handle error!
}

try
{
    auto jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap.at(tabName);
    if (! (*jsFile << contentofJSFile))  // write to JS file
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
catch (const std::out_of_range & )
{
     // handle error
}
```

The program still may not work at this point, but you are now in much better position to determine why.

Off topic: There doesn't seem to be any need for a `std::shared_ptr`. Others have recommended switching to a `std::unique_ptr`. I'll go a step further. There may not be a need for a pointer at all.

```
std::map<std::string, std::ofstream> m_jsTabFilesMap; // no pointers 
std::ofstream temp(jsFilename);
if (temp)
{
    m_jsTabFilesMap.emplace(fileKey, std::move(temp)); //emplace, not insert
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
try
{
    auto &jsFile = m_jsTabFilesMap.at(tabName);
    if (!(jsFile << contentofJSFile))
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
catch (const std::out_of_range &)
{
    // handle error
}
```